# iOS 8 - Search display controller shows white space at right

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Using search display controller in a app, it works fine in iOS 7 but in iOS 8 it shows a white space at right side of search display table as follows

[image]

Tried a lot but not getting any solution.

Comment: Any chance this is being run on a wider phone? If you are using custom tableView cells, make sure that the background (the red) is not hard coded to fit a smaller phone

Comment: @DevC it's not hard coded, I'm checking on iPhone 5S with iOS 7 works fine; but with iPhone 5S with iOS 8 gives above problem

Comment: Did you check the accessoryType of the cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of layoutMargins. Try adding this method to your table view's delegate and see if things work as intended:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

}
```